# Logitech Harmony keyboard possible in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, logitech

I did a lot of searching but could not find any way to get the [Logitech Harmony Smart Keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/product/harmony-smart-keyboard) working on Ubuntu 14.04. Is there really no way?

I can configure it with the smartphone app or windows, but so far Ubuntu does not even recognize the USB plugin.

Comment: What model is your Harmony?

Comment: I put a link into the description. Its part number PN 915-000225.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Linux Harmony project.  No support from Logictech.  Here is the [Webpage](http://www.phildev.net/harmony/).

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=a86b12d4203fd7a3be853dc281eddf28&t=781059) is a really good How-To on how to setup it up.

To find out about Harmony models that are supported, go [here](http://www.phildev.net/harmony/supported_models.shtml).

You can take a look at congruity.  This software will allow you to program your Logitech Harmony universal remote control! In addition to providing software that works in UNIX (which logitech's software doesn't support).<sup>[Concordance](http://www.phildev.net/harmony/)</sup>

[congruity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/congruity/) is a GUI application for programming Logitech Harmony. congruity builds upon the work of the concordance project, which provides the underlying communication.<sup>[congruity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/congruity/)</sup>

Hope it helps.